# C++ different minmax implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

As You may (not) know using `std::minmax` with auto and temporary arguments may be dangerous. Following code for example is UB because `std::minmax` returns pair of references, not values:

```
auto fun(){
    auto res = std::minmax(3, 4);
    return res.first;
}
```

I would like to ask if there is possibility to make `std::minmax` function act safely or at least safer without any overhead? I came up with a solution like this, but I am not completely sure if it is equivalent to current `minmax` as generated assembly is different for stl-like implementation and mine. So the question is: what are the possible problems/drawbacks of my implementation of `minmax` in relation to `std`-like one:

```
//below is std-like minmax
template< class T > 
constexpr std::pair<const T&,const T&> std_minmax( const T& a, const T& b ){
    return (b < a) ? std::pair<const T&, const T&>(b, a)
            : std::pair<const T&, const T&>(a, b);
}

//below is my minmax implementation
template< class T > 
constexpr std::pair<T, T> my_minmax( T&& a, T&& b ){
    return (b < a) ? std::pair<T, T>(std::forward<T>(b), std::forward<T>(a))
            : std::pair<T, T>(std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<T>(b));
}
```

[Live demo at godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/GJismx)

---

As some of You claim it is unclear what I am asking, I would like to reword a bit what I want. I would like to write function which works exactly like `std::minmax`, but if given one temporary value - returns `std::pair<T, T>` instead of `std::pair<const T &, const T &>`. Secondly, while doing it I would like to avoid any unnecessary moving, copying of data and so forth.

Comment: Non-const references prefers second overload. Mixed lvalue/rvalue have trouble deducing. And probably a lot more.

Comment: @PasserBy I am not suggesting using both of them. I am asking about unexpected behaviour or performance differences between the first and second one. The mixed lval/rval one is true though, how could it me mitigated?

Comment: It depends on what your desired semantics are, but the first thing is to have two or variadic template parameters.

Comment: @PasserBy Generally to be as close as possible to `std::minmax` semantics but without its danger

Comment: Your live demo lacks optimization option, e.g., `-O2`. Without, you cannot argue about performance / generated assembly.

Comment: @bartop Not at all relevant now. A compiler knows the values, so it optimizes away all the comparison. Try something as this: https://godbolt.org/z/PdrwNB. Alternatively, you can for instance read compared numbers from `std::cin` or from `argv[1]`, etc. Generally, I prefer my solution, since it cannot inline functions and you clearly see the generated assembly.

Comment: @DanielLangr: There is no point comparing `minmax` for `int` without inline, because it will be inlined.

Comment: From interface, for `struct D : public C {/**/};` `std_minmax<C>(c1, d2)` would require `my_minmax</*const*/C&>(c1, d2)` (as types should be the same for the 2 arguments). (might also apply when mixing signs)

Comment: @Jarod42 What can be done about it? Two template arguments?

Comment: With 2 different template arguments, you have the issue of return value type (yes `std::common_type` might help but constness has to be handled too, and result it might be surprising/non intuitive)...

Comment: can you please make this question a bit more selfcontained? without reading the other question that has an answer and two dupes it isnt clear why you say `std::minmax` would be unsafe. If i got it correctly you want a `minmax` that also works for temporaries, right?

Comment: Unclear what you want to compare exactly ? your method acts differently with rvalue, has different interface, do you want to know the difference for (`const`) l-value ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I want to compare functionality - what I mean is to make `std::minmax` replaceable in any situation with my implementation + make it safe

Comment: IIUC, you want the resulting `pair` member to be 1) a (const) lvalue reference to the corresponding function argument, if this is an lvalue or 2) a value moved from that argument, if it is an rvalue. Is it right? Just to clarify.

Comment: @DanielLangr That's correct, perhaps I will change qestion to be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve. You wrote:

> without any overhead

but your solution will copy lvalue arguments. Is it what you want?

Anyway, you cannot use two forwarding references with the same template parameter this way, since it will fail if both function arguments have different categories:

```
template <typename T> void f(T&& a, T&& b) { }

int main() {
  int a = 3;
  f(a, 1);  // error: template argument deduction/substitution failed
}
```

For the first function argument, `T` would be deduced as `int&`, and for second as `int`.

---

If you want to remove any copying, the only possibility is the member of the resulting `pair` to be:

1. a (const) *lvalue reference* to the corresponding function argument in case it is an *lvalue*,
2. a *value* moved from that argument if is it an *rvalue*.

I don't think this is possible to achieve. Consider:

```
std::string a("hello");
auto p = minmax(a, std::string("world"));
```

Here the resulting type would be `std::pair<std::string&, std::string>`. However, in case of

```
auto p = minmax(a, std::string("earth"));
```

the resulting type would be different, namely `std::pair<std::string, std::string&>`.

Therefore, the resulting type would depend on a runtime condition (which generally requires runtime polymorphism).

---

**UPDATE**

Out of curiosity, I just came up with a wrapper that can hold some object either by (const) *pointer* or by *value*:

```
template <typename T>
class val_or_ptr {
   std::variant<T, const T*> v_;
public:
   val_or_ptr(const T& arg) : v_(&arg) { }
   val_or_ptr(T&& arg) : v_(std::move(arg)) { }
   const T& get() const { return v_.index() ? *std::get<const T*>(v_) : std::get<T>(v_); }
};
```

With that, you can define `minmax` as:

```
template <typename T, typename U,
          typename V = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>, std::decay_t<T>>>
std::pair<val_or_ptr<V>, val_or_ptr<V>> minmax(T&& a, U&& b) {
   if (b < a) return { std::forward<U>(b), std::forward<T>(a) };
   else return { std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<U>(b) };
}
```

Live demo is here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/N3kdI4hzllBGFWVH

This is very basic implementation, but it should prevent copying both from lvalue and rvalue arguments of `minmax`.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is when `T` is an r-value reference then copy it instead of returning an r-value reference:

```
#include <utility>

template<class T>
std::pair<T, T> minmax(T&& a, T&& b) {
    if(a < b)
        return {a, b};
    return {b, a};
}
```

When the argument is an r-value reference `T` is deduced as a non-reference type:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int const b = 2;
    minmax(1, 1); // std::pair<int, int>
    minmax(a, a); // std::pair<int&, int&>
    minmax(b, b); // std::pair<const int&, const int&>
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not work with mixed rvalue/lvalue arguments (template deduction for `T` will fail then). It's the same as for OP's solution, but he/she asked for a better alternative to `std::minmax`, so I would suppose he/she actually wants to support mixed-category arguments.

Comment: @DanielLangr It doesn't support mixed rvalue/lvalue arguments by design.

Answer (score 1):

With `C++17` it is possible to use `constexpr if` to tie lvalue args and copy everything else. With `C++11` I would probably think twice before building an angle brackets moster with a scary look for such a simple use case.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nzSrjH), [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49aaa86e1beab957)

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) minmax(T&& x, T&& y)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(x)>)
        return std::minmax(std::forward<T>(x), std::forward<T>(y));
    else {
        auto const res = std::minmax(x, y);
        return std::make_pair(res.first, res.second);
    }
}
```

To support mixed l/r values you probably need two template params, 4 cases in the if/else, and `std::cref(res.xxx)` as an argument to std::make_pair for partial.

Comment: Note that this will not work with mixed rvalue/lvalue arguments (template deduction for `T` will fail then). It's the same as for OP's solution, but he/she asked for a better alternative to `std::minmax`, so I would suppose he/she actually wants to support mixed-category arguments.

Comment: @DanielLangr - I added a suggestion to the bottom of the answer